# How to call a method on a Angular Web Component (Custom Element)

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element

I have created an Angular Web Component like below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dlx-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  open() {
    console.log('open');
  }

  close() {
    console.log('close');
  }
    
}
```

and in my app module

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  
  ngDoBootstrap() {
      this.defineElement(SliderComponent, 'dlx-slider');
  }
  
  private defineElement(component: any, elementName: string) {
    const el = createCustomElement(component, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define(elementName, el);
  }

}
```

everything is working fine and I have embedded it in a simple HTML page like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TMIBot</title>
        <base href="/">
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    
        <title>Test Angular Elements</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://urltomy/dist/dlx-styles-1.0.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button id="button">Open Slider </button>
        <dlx-slider id="slider"></dlx-slider>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://urltomy/dist/dlx-chatbot-1.0.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to call the `open` method on it. I can't find a way for that

```html
<script>
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('button Click');
  const slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
  console.log(slider);
  slider.open();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, any `@Input` should generate a corresponding attribute on the element.  Can you make a `state` input, watch it with `ngOnChanges` and then change the attribute value in native js?

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 8 I just did

```
@Input()
doFoo() {
   console.log('we did it');
}
```

And it worked

Comment: but only after document.appendChild(). And there is no solution, as I now, to make it work before document.appendChild().

Comment: Please note that in the inside of the doFoo() function the "this" pointer is pointing to the plain HTML element rather than to the class instance

Comment: You can make `this` refer to the class instance by binding `this` to the method as explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22114#issuecomment-569311422 `this.host.nativeElement.drive = this.drive.bind(this);`

Answer (score 4):

Using setter and assign a value to call a function may not so pretty.

So I have made a little change:

```js
@Input()
  get close() {
    return () => doClose();
  }
```

Now we can call `close` function instead of assigning a value.

Answer (score 4):

Why not expose the method on the element itself?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ng-comp-ce',
    templateUrl: './ng-comp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ng-comp.component.scss'],
})
export class NGComponentCustomElement {

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.element.nativeElement.myFunc = () => this.myFunc();
    }
  
    myFunc() {
      console.log('hello from component');
    }
}
```

And call it with JS in your page

```
 document.querySelector('ng-comp-ce').myFunc();
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem with you. Using setter like the example above is not working. But If you add @Input() on your setter, you can call that setter to call your method.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  set open(state:string) {
    doOpen();
  }

  @Input()
  set close(state:string) {
    doClose();
  }

  doOpen() {
    console.log('open');
  }

  doClose() {
    console.log('close');
  }
}
```

Your client javascript code should be as follows.

```
<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('#button');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('button Click');
        const slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
        console.log(slider);
        // Call open method
        slider.open = 'open';
        // Call close method
        slider.close = 'close';
    });
</script>
```

Also if you want to retrieve async data on your method and put them on any property, you can get a **ChangeDetectorRef** from constructor and call **ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges** method. If you do not, component html do not know any changes on property.

Comment: thanks, let me try it sometime later and if it was working I mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

`Setter` and `Getter` may give the option to invoke the method.

### In ts file

```
      set state(state:string) {
        console.log("state changed ", state);
      }

      get state() {
        return "IN"; 
      }
```

### Call set attribute to invoke the openState setter method.

```
<script>
        const button = document.querySelector('#button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('button Click');
            const slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
            console.log(slider);
            //slider.open();
             setTimeout(() => {
           slider.setAttribute('state', 'OUT');
           }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: my question is about custom element, not slider

Comment: custom elements are written to be used in other web applications such as simple web pages, adding an output is not acting as method, see this for more info on web components
https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b

Comment: Did you try with setter and getter ?

Comment: thanks for answer, I need to call the method, this is just a sample, please focus on calling a method not setting attributes, I updated my question to just `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

## Angular 9

In your web component `<my-slider>` we can define methods as setters - and additionally we can define events in traditional way

```js
    @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
 
    @Input() set myFunction(data: {str: string, n: number}) {    
      // ... your code

      this.myEvent.emit({xyz:'abc', data});  // fire example event
    }
```

In your angular project you can use this component as follows

**html template** (note - we can handle events in angular way!)

```js
    <my-slider #myslider (myEvent)="sliderEventHandler($event)" ></my-slider>
```

**ts file** (we use `@ViewChild` to avoid using ID)

```js
    @ViewChild('myslider') myslider: any;
    
    // and in some method - we execute web-component function
    this.myslider.nativeElement.myFunction = {str: "Alice in ...", n: 10};
```

in event handler we get `CustomEvent` object and we can get event data from it as follows

```js
    sliderEventHandler(event: CustomEvent) {
      console.log('event data!', event.detail);
    }
```

Comment: hi, what i can do with sliderEventHandler is undefined?

Comment: @IgorZinchenko ask your question as separate SO question - and give more details there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
export class MyClass {
    
    constructor(private host: ElementRef) {
        // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22114#issuecomment-569311422
        this.host.nativeElement.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
    }

    @Input()
    public myMethod(): void {
        this.doSomethingHere();
    }
}
```